# Yii CGridView make url in data column

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii and trying to make modify one application which use

```
zii.widgets.grid.CGridView
```

I am trying to pass 2 divs in one column and also trying to get URL too.

This is my code:

```
'value' => 'CHtml::tag("div", array("class"=>""),
 "<div class=cname>.$data->name."</div>".
 "<br><div class=cname1> Status | Copy "."</div>"
)',
```

In the above I want to put link to Status and Copy

The code which generate URL is this:

```
'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->id, Yii::app()->createUrl("overview/cam", array("uid" => $data->id)))',
```

I have tried many options but nothing is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `'url'` instead of `'value'` in CGridView

```
'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("overview/cam", array("uid" => $data->id))',
```

If you use value then do something like this..

```
 'value'=>CHtml::link('$data->id,array('overview/cam','uid'=>$data->id));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Url you should use

```
'value' => 'CHtml::link(  $data->id ,
         array( Yii::app()->createUrl("overview/cam", array("uid" => $data->id))))',
```

Comment: Hello, its two Urls plz

Comment: explain  better i don'tb understand